# Cronjob not working

Tags: php, cron

I have added a new line to my crontab file, but this line won't work.
This is the code of my crontab file:

```
# Music scrobbler
# Every 5 minutes
*/5 * * * * php -f /var/www/Music/scrobble/index.php


# Radio scrobbler
# Every Minute
*/1 * * * * php -f /var/www/fmstats/Scrobble/cron/scrobble.php > /fmstats.log
```

The first line works perfectly, but the second does nothing. It should output a list of radio stations but fmstats.log is always empty. It should also add a row to a database wich doesn't happen either.

If I execute the file manualy using the console or via the browser, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a question of permissions.
Doublecheck: What user is running the cronjob, and the permissios on /fmstats.log

I quess if you change your path to the outputfile like lets sayD
/tmp/fmstats.log
you will get a file in your /tmp folder.

You should also try a full path:

```
/1 * * * * php -f /var/www/fmstats/Scrobble/cron/scrobble.php > /var/www/fmstats/Scrobble/cron/fmstats.log
```

Comment: The output isn't the priority, the php script sends data to the database and this doesn't happen either.

The script is being run as root, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes. It could be possible that the script doesn't execute because of the permission error. Have you tried the full path Version?